# REACT TABLE- Hide rows in table & reset button to display hidden rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-table

In my column `Show` there is a `switch` button (`Toggle` doesn't seems working in sandbox, maybe because of `tailwindcss`? but it works in local...) when you click on it, it will turn the selected row into gray (as if the row is disabled but you can still view the content).
We may have also the possibility to switch again and the original row (without gray) appears.

The `VisibilityIcon` button above the table  will remove from all the table the gray/disabled rows (not working either). And a `VisibilityoffIcon` button that resets all (we get the original table).

Here what I have done but when I click on the `Toggle` I get errors and all the table is hidden:

```
export default function MenuDisplay() {
    const { menuId } = useParams();
    const { match } = JsonRules;
    const dataFindings = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const toggler_disabled = () => {
    disabled ? setDisabled(false) : setDisabled(true);
  };


    const data = useMemo(
        () => [
            //some headers ....    
            {
                Header: 'Show',
                accessor: (row) =>  
                  <Toggle  onClick ={toggler_disabled} value={disabled} onChange= 
                 {setDisabled} />
            }
        ],[]
    );
    ...
    return (
        {
            disabled?
                <Table 
                    data = { dataFindings }
                    columns = { data }
                />
            : null
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keep a map of item ids that are selected and toggle these values via the `Toggle` component.
2. Use separate state for the toggle button to filter the selected items.
3. Implement a row props getter.

Example:

MenuDisplay

```
function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;

  // toggle show/hide button
  const [hideSelected, setHideSelected] = useState(false);

  // select rows by item id
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  const rowSelectHandler = (id) => (checked) => {
    setSelected((selected) => ({
      ...selected,
      [id]: checked
    }));
  };

  const toggleShow = () => setHideSelected((hide) => !hide);

  const matchData = (
    match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? []
  ).filter(({ _id }) => {
    if (hideSelected) {
      return !selected[_id];
    }
    return true;
  });

  const getRowProps = (row) => {
    return {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: selected[row.values.id] ? "lightgrey" : "white"
      }
    };
  };

  const data = [
    {
      // add item id to row data
      Header: "id",
      accessor: (row) => row._id
    },
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>{row.name}</Link>
      )
    },
    {
      Header: "Description",
      accessor: (row) => row.description
    },
    {
      Header: "Dishes",
      accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
      id: "dishes",
      Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
    },
    {
      Header: "Show",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <Toggle
          value={selected[row._id]}
          onChange={rowSelectHandler(row._id)}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  const initialState = {
    sortBy: [
      { desc: false, id: "id" },
      { desc: false, id: "description" }
    ],
    hiddenColumns: ["dishes", "id"] // <-- hide id column too
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleShow}>
        {hideSelected ? <VisibilityOffIcon /> : <VisibilityIcon />}
      </button>

      <Table
        data={matchData}
        columns={data}
        initialState={initialState}
        withCellBorder
        withRowBorder
        withSorting
        withPagination
        rowProps={getRowProps} // <-- pass rowProps getter
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Table

```
export default function Table({
  className,
  data,
  columns,
  initialState,
  withCellBorder,
  withRowBorder,
  withSorting,
  withPagination,
  withColumnSelect,
  rowProps = () => ({}) // <-- destructure row props getter
}) {
  ...

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      ...
      <div className="....">
        <table className="w-full" {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead className="....">
            ...
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {(withPagination ? page : rows).map((row) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr
                  className={....}
                  {...row.getRowProps(rowProps(row))} // <-- call row props getter
                >
                  ...
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-table-hide-rows-in-table-reset-button-to-display-hidden-rows]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Why do we have to add row props getter in `Table` ?

Comment: @Zokulko I wish I had a better answer for that *other than* that this just seems to be the way the `react-table` maintainers implemented it. After reading through the docs and a brief google search this is what I was able to get working. It's not an uncommon pattern though.

Comment: I tried to modifie your code by a new one using api: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-hide-rows-in-table-reset-button-to-display-hidden-rows-forked-mne47w?file=/src/MenuDisplayApi.jsx) with json file from my api, you can see the output for `menuId:1` in `match_api_menuId1.json`. I have all my data printed in my table, the issue concerns the selected rows : when I click on the visibilityIconOff, then the row goes away, but it's working ONLY for the first click, since you click on the show rectangle, then the row goes away without clicking on visibility icon... Now I want

Comment: Now I want to display all the rows where the `apply:1` and if there are not apply the value `apply:0`. I want to keep a trace of the apply menus, by returning to my databse `apply:0` or `apply:1`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `useMemo` under row data that memoize all rows which have the same click event without dependencies. If you want to call `useMemo` with an updated state, you can implement it this way

```
//`show` is your state
//`data` is your rows
useMemo(() => data, [show])
```

And the second problem is you track the `show` state which is only a true/false value. If you want to have multiple row states, you need to keep it as an array.

Here is the full code with some explanation (You also can check [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-xfh7xb?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx:0-2333))

```
import Table from "./Table";
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import JsonData from "./match.json";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import VisibilityOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff";
import VisibilityIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Visibility";

export default function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;
  const [hiddenRows, setHiddenRows] = useState([]);

  const matchData = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];

  //update hidden row list
  const updateHiddenRows = (rowId) => {
    if (hiddenRows.includes(rowId)) {
      //remove the current clicked row from the hidden row list
      setHiddenRows(hiddenRows.filter((row) => row !== rowId));
    } else {
      //add the current clicked row from the hidden row list
      setHiddenRows([...hiddenRows, rowId]);
    }
  };

  const data = useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: (row) =>
        //check current row is in hidden rows or not
        !hiddenRows.includes(row._id) && (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>
            {row.name}
          </Link>
        )
    },
    {
      Header: "Description",
      //check current row is in hidden rows or not
      accessor: (row) => !hiddenRows.includes(row._id) && row.description
    },
    {
      Header: "Dishes",
      //check current row is in hidden rows or not
      accessor: (row) => !hiddenRows.includes(row._id) && row.dishes,
      Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
    },
    {
      Header: "Show",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <button onClick={() => updateHiddenRows(row._id)}>
          {!hiddenRows.includes(row._id) ? (
            <VisibilityIcon>Show</VisibilityIcon>
          ) : (
            <VisibilityOffIcon>Show</VisibilityOffIcon>
          )}
        </button>
      )
    }
  ], [hiddenRows]);

  const initialState = {
    sortBy: [
      { desc: false, id: "id" },
      { desc: false, id: "description" },
      { desc: false, id: "dishes" }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        data={matchData}
        columns={data}
        initialState={initialState}
        withCellBorder
        withRowBorder
        withSorting
        withPagination
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, when is it advisable to useMemo, because I use it everywhere as it helps to improve performance

Comment: If you want to call `useMemo`, you should pass dependencies for it. For example, with the above logic, you can pass dependency `hiddenRows` like this `useMemo(() => [], [hiddenRows])`. It means whenever you update `hiddenRows` state, your data will be rememoized again. @Zokulko

Comment: here is [the playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-xfh7xb?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx), you can try it out @Zokulko

Comment: thanks (even if it is not exactly the answer of my question :) )...This time, I 've re-modified my question, now I don't know how to do that, if you can help me..